# Escaping backslash in the LIKE statement works in SELECT query but does not work in UPDATE query

Tags: mysql

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE `object_type` LIKE 'App\\\\Models\\\\%';
```

it works fine.

But when I run the following query:

```
UPDATE `sss_notifications` SET `object_type`=CONCAT('App\Models\', object_type) WHERE `object_type` NOT LIKE 'App\\\\Models\\\\%';
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:
Unknown command '\\'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\\'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\\'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\\'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a subtle difference in the functionality between LIKE and NOT LIKE. Does it still error if you run the update with the WHERE clause like this `WHERE NOT (object_type LIKE 'App\\\\Models\\\\%');`

Comment: @DarrenH I had other issues with the query and I wrote it in the answer. Replacing the where clause with the alternative you have suggested works in a similar way.

Answer (score 2):

The backslash before the single quote in the `CONCAT` function escapes the single quote. So, it was parsing the query as something else and was throwing the error. By escaping the backslash before the single quote fixed it.

```
UPDATE `sss_notifications` SET `object_type`=CONCAT('App\\Models\\', object_type) WHERE `object_type` NOT LIKE 'App\\\\Models\\\\%';
```

I also needed to escape the other backslash after 'App' in the `CONCAT` function.